# Upgraded from 13.04->13.10; "Error occurred while mounting /boot/efi"

Tags: 13.10, uefi

I upgraded to 13.10 this morning, and can no longer launch Ubuntu.  Specifically, I'm greeted with the following message: "An error occurred while mounting /boot/efi  (Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery)"

I ran Boot Recovery to no avail -- the output of the report is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6693898/

One potentially relevant thing I've noticed is the following error: "FAT-fs (sda1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found" which seems similar to this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1221330) but I'm totally not smart enough to understand if it is or what to do if that's the case.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated :(

Answer (score 1):

@RodSmith - Thank you for the helpful answer!

UPDATE: It was indeed [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1221330).  I ended up recreating the /boot/efi partition (using GParted on Boot Recovery).  I then reinstalled Ubuntu 13.10 again.  This had the downside of losing a bunch of my apps, but I was due for a house cleaning anyways.

I think Rod's suggestion of copying the /boot/efi files off, and then back again, would have been the best course of action if I wanted to salvage more.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how I ended up in this situation.  It kind of sucks that I had to bang my head against this issue for like 10 hours, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dual-booting with Windows 8 or 8.1, you *must* disable the Fast Startup feature in Windows, as described [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html), among many other places. This feature turns a shutdown into a suspend-to-disk (hibernate), which leaves filesystems in an inconsistent state. This can result in an inability to mount the filesystem(s) in question from Linux, although I don't recall offhand if the "IO charset iso8859-1" error message is a possible symptom in Linux. (I suspect not, offhand, although I'm not positive of that.) Note that the Windows Fast Startup feature is *not* the same as a feature with the same or similar name in many EFIs, so disabling such a feature in your firmware is *not* adequate (or even necessary) to fix this issue.

In the short term (for a single boot), the EFI System Partition (ESP), which is mounted at `/boot/efi`, need not be mounted for most day-to-day activities. Thus, pressing `S` to skip mounting it should get Ubuntu to boot. This should enable more diagnostics and repair attempts. I recommend:

- Once you've booted, try mounting the filesystem manually, as in `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`. This may produce a more informative error message; or you can type `dmesg | tail` after a mount attempt to look for anything that might be recorded to the kernel ring buffer. Note that if you *do* get the partition to mount, you can unmount it with `sudo umount /boot/efi` if you want to try again (say, to try various options to figure out what's working and what's not working).
- The `/etc/fstab` file contains entries that describe what to mount where and how to mount each filesystem. Try locating the entry for `/boot/efi` and do a Web search to learn more about this file. This won't help you per se, but you may discover a mount option that will fix the problem, in which case editing the `/etc/fstab` file may be in order.
- In a worst-case scenario, backing up the ESP, umounting it, creating a fresh filesystem on it (via `sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -n ESP /dev/sda1`, re-mounting it, and restoring it may be necessary. A file-level backup (via `cp`, `tar`, or the like) should be adequate; but you may need to adjust the `/etc/fstab` file because the serial number (`UUID=` in `/etc/fstab`) will almost certainly change. Of course, you'll need to successfully mount the ESP in order to back it up.
- It's conceivable that your kernel has been built incorrectly; or more likely, that your initial RAM disk (initrd) has been built incorrectly. This type of problem is difficult for most users to overcome, although Ubuntu's [`update-initramfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-initramfs.8.html) tool can help with the latter.